# Install python libraries using shell script

Tags: python, shell, numpy

I'm very new in python, sorry if my question is very basic.I have a shell script that using it to run a .py file on a cluster. Here is my shell script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    module add python/2.6
    python Myfile.py
```

Python has been installed on the cluster but some of the libraries and packages needs to be installed. For example, I need to install Numpy package, is there any way that I can do it inside my shell script or my .py file before "import" it?

Thanks

Comment: You may try [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip)

Comment: As @skyuuka said, [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) will achieve exactly what you're asking. Check out [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) while you're at it.

Comment: You can also consider `setuptools` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). After you install it, just run `easy_install Numpy` in your shell script.

Comment: Actually I do not have root access, so I can not use "sudo" :(

Comment: I would suspect most clusters would have numpy available, maybe through a tool like `softenv`. Maybe talk to the cluster admin about it?

Answer (score 4):

For this (and similar) use case, I would recommend a combination of [*pip*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [*virtualenv*](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

You would install *pip* into your system  *Python* install (i.e. `sudo apt-get install python-pip`), and then install *virtualenv* via *pip*, i.e. `pip install virtualenv`).

You can then create a specific *virtualenv* for this project. This represents a sandboxed environment with specific versions of libraries that are specified traditionally through a *requirements* file (using the `-r` option), but can also be specified individually through the command line.

You would do this via command like `virtualenv venv_test`, which will create a *virtualenv* directory named *venv_test* in the current directory. You can then run *pip* from that *virtualenv*'s **bin** dir to install packages.

For example, to install the *flask* package in that *virutalenv*, you would run:

> venv_test/bin/pip install flask

You can then either run `source venv_test/bin/activate` to put the current shell into the *virtualenv*'s, or invoke a script directly from the *virtualenv*'s interpreter, i.e.:

> venv_test/bin/python foo.py

Here's link to a [virtualenv introduction](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/) for some additional details/steps.